# how to add a range of IP addresses in debian

Tags: debian, ip

I want add a range or IP address 192.168.1.128 to 192.168.1.254 to my debian host
I　know, there is an range file (such as ifcfg-eth0-range0) in RedHat/CentOS, they have IPADDR_START/IPADDR_END, but how to do in debian?

Answer (score 2):

You could an ifup to use a script to add the addresses for you.  Create the following script as `/etc/network/if-up.d/eth0`

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$IFACE" eq "eth0" ]; then
    for IP in {128..254}; do
        ip addr add 192.168.1.${IP}/24 dev eth0
    done
fi

# EOF
```

/24 should be replaced by the appropriate subnet mask.

A corresponding script in `/etc/network/if-down.d/eth0` should be created using "ip addr" del in place of "ip addr add".

Be sure to run `chmod +x` on both scripts.

You can test the script using the command `IFACE=eth0 /etc/network/if-up.d/eth0`.

You could also create the file as `/usr/local/sbin/eth0-aliases` and run it from an up option in `/etc/network/interfaces`.  Add `up /usr/local/sbin/eth0-aliases` to the eth0 stanza.   If you use this mechanism you don't need the if condition in the script.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it manually for each interface. Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and add each one to that e.g.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
auto eth0:1
auto eth0:2
iface eth0 inet static
         address 192.168.10.1
         netmask 255.255.255.0
         gateway 192.168.10.100

iface eth0:1 inet static
         address 192.168.10.2
         netmask 255.255.255.0
         gateway 192.168.10.100

iface eth0:2 inet static
         address 192.168.10.3
         netmask 255.255.255.0
         gateway 192.168.10.100
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Linode published a great article on how to do this

http://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/Multiple_IPs

Comment: Note that this doesn't cover how to add a range.  It just describes the "descriptive method", i.e. multiple `iface eth0:1` stanzas.

Comment: This link has rotted. While you're at it, add something relevant to this answer so it can stand alone.

Answer (score -1):

You can probably only add every IP on its own to a virtual interface. Refer to [this FAQ entry](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bind-alias-range-of-ip-address-in-linux/).